# Display image(preloaders) before content is loaded WebPart - SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plug-in called `lightSlider` and I notice it doesn't display the whole content on first load until I refresh.

I have tried using

```
1. windows.load, 
2. ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded,
3. setTimeout etc...
```

But still no luck.

Just need some tip or advice on how I could tackle this.

I was thinking of showing some preload image for a while before content to make sure the html if fully created

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your JQuery inside `$(document).ready(function)({});`

Additionally, if you're consuming data from SharePoint lists, you have to make sure the plug-in code doesn't run until after all of your SharePoint data is returned by using promises.